# Using GA with time series data

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to use the GA package for feature selection on a linear model.  Some of my data has been lagged, creating N/A values in the data.  I am using the following code to start the process:

```
ctrl <- gafsControl(functions = caretGA)
obj <- gafs(x = x, 
            y = y,
            iters = 100,
            gafsControl = ctrl,
            method = "lm")
```

I am new to the GA package so I am sure I am missing something.  But I keep getting the following error.

Error in quantile.default(y, probs = seq(0, 1, length = cuts)) : 
  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

Is it coming from my lag function or something else?

Comment: How about removing the NA values from both x and y.

Comment: That was the solution.  I should have tried that before writing this thread